# System-monitoring with Cacti: How to execute arbitrary script when threshold reached?

Tags: monitoring, performance-monitoring, cacti, system-monitoring

**When doing system-monitor with [Cacti](http://www.cacti.net/)[1], can you execute an arbitrary script when a threshold is reached, yes or no?**

**If yes, how?**

[1] I was planning on using the Cacti plugin [Thold](http://docs.cacti.net/plugin:thold) but as far as I can tell this only allows you to email someone when a threshold is reached... not execute an arbitrary script.

---

I found an [official post from the author of Thold](http://blog.cactiusers.org/2009/02/25/the-future-of-thold/) which talks about ["Alternate alerts... running scripts"](http://blog.cactiusers.org/2009/02/25/the-future-of-thold/) which is the functionality I need (executing an arbitrary script when a threshold is reached).

But other than that post, I can't seem to find any examples or posts on whether 'executing an arbitrary script when a threshold is reached' is a working feature and/or how to configure said feature.

Answer (score 2):

Here https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/cacti-08/9781849513920/ch10s05.html there is some documentation about installing and configure thold with some screenshots.
I haven't never used it but I understand that you can only watch in the cacti homepage which treeshold has been reached.
In my opinion cacti is a useful tool for capacity planning but it wasn't developed for monitoring and to generate alarms. There are other monitoring solutions more useful to generate alarm and execute script when an alarm is generated for example Nagios,Centreon,OMD,Zabbix...